# Cannot stop then start Geode server with a disk store

Tags: gemfire, geode

I start Geode with a disk store using the [example config](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/10/managing/disk_storage/using_disk_stores.html). Then if I stop the server and start it again I get:

Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected multiple disk store initialization files named "BACKUPDeal.if". This disk store directories must only contain one initialization file.`

If I remove the if file, then the error is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The init file "D:\deal\BACKUPdeal.if" does not exist. If it no longer exists then delete the following files to be able to create this disk store. Existing oplogs are: [D:\deal\BACKUPdeal_1.drf, D:\deal\BACKUPdeal_1.crf]`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you detail the exact commands you're running to start/stop the servers and any config/properties you're using?

Comment: @JensD its `<disk-store name="deal" compaction-threshold="40" 
           auto-compact="false" allow-force-compaction="true"
        max-oplog-size="512" queue-size="10000"  
        time-interval="15" write-buffer-size="65536"
        disk-usage-warning-percentage="80"
        disk-usage-critical-percentage="98">
       <disk-dirs>
              <disk-dir>d:\deal</disk-dir>
              <disk-dir dir-size="20480">d:\deal</disk-dir>
       </disk-dirs>
</disk-store>`

Comment: aargh so it's using the same disk dir location twice....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [example config](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/10/managing/disk_storage/using_disk_stores.html) uses 2 disk stores and I had renamed these to the same store, therefore it couldn't initialize 2 disk stores out of 1. To solve it I removed the 2nd disk store from the config like so:

`<disk-store name="deal" 
compaction-threshold="40" 
auto-compact="false" 
allow-force-compaction="true" 
max-oplog-size="512" 
queue-size="10000" 
time-interval="15" 
write-buffer-size="65536" 
disk-usage-warning-percentage="80" 
disk-usage-critical-percentage="98"> 
<disk-dirs> 
<disk-dir>d:\deal</disk-dir> 
</disk-dirs> 
</disk-store>`